# converting char* to boost::array for sockets use

Tags: c++, arrays, boost, boost-asio

I'd like to use the method "read_some()" of boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket to fill a buffer represented as a char*.

Here is my method implementation so far:

```
template<class charType>
int receive_some(charType* buffer, int size)
{
     int total_received = 0;

     boost::array<charType, size> buf;
     while (1)
     {
         int received = 0;
         boost::system::error_code error;
         received = _socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buf), error);
         if (error == boost::asio::error::eof)
         { 
             break;
         }
         std::cout.write(buf.data(), received);
         total_received += received;
      }

    return total_received;

}
```

My problem is I don't see how to convert my charType* buffer into boost::array buf. It seems expensive to iterate over the elements of my boost::array at the end of the process just to fill-in the buffer object...

Any idea ?

Comment: Why is it templated? Do you expect to receive anything else than bytes from the network?

Comment: Maybe he receives vegetables from the sockets... in that case it would have to be a template. But yeah... template not needed here.

Comment: I could receive char*, unsigned char * etc, no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
template<class charType>
int receive_some(charType* buffer, int size)
{
     int total_received = 0;

     while (1)
     {
         int received = 0;
         boost::system::error_code error;
         received = _socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buffer, size), error);
         if (error == boost::asio::error::eof)
         { 
             break;
         }
         std::cout.write(buffer, received);
         total_received += received;
      }

    return total_received;

}
```

The [boost::asio::buffer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer.html) function has a lot of overloads to allow to create an asio buffer from diffrent types of sources.

It's worth noting that `size` has to be the number of bytes to read into `buffer` and not the number of `charType`.

Bonus tip: As comments pointed out, that template is suspicious, the best you could do with it is directly write into wide strings but that might better be somewhere else than in a `read_some` function (actually it might even be better nowhere), in a network function you deal with bytes not characters so you'd better take a simple `char*` or even `void*` as a type for the `buffer` parameter.

Comment: thanks ! working :) and thanks for the additional tip